# Is it right assume the greater the precession of a type of particle in the same magnetic field the slower the particle spin?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment, precession

Is it right that the greater the Larmor frequency of a particle measured for same magnetic field applied the slower a particle spin is? I read these articles http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/top.html#top and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/larmor.html where the invertional proportionality between precession rate and spin rate is mentioned.It is considered that the spin differs from type of particles but it is invariant regarding time.So please don't think that the question implies that the particle spin is not constant in time as the top spin is....

[A little video(kaleidoscope) homage to the kaleidoscopic way(wavefunction) of motion of the electron inside the hydrogen atom...]
https://youtu.be/6Icy4RkXuE8

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking: What do you mean by a particle's spin being "slower"? The Larmor frequency is by definition about the speed of a *precession* of an angular momentum, not about the speed of a rotation as such.

Comment: @ACuriousMind No. I know that the spin of a particle cannot change with time therefore being a constant but I am asking just as the precession rate is inversly proportional to the spin rate for a common top can we extend this fact on subatomic particles where one type of particles has high precession rate measured as larmour freq. and another one has a smaller precession rate so by deduction we can say as precession rate is inversely proportional to the spin the particle with higher precession e.g. L. freq. should rotate slower than the one with smaller precession rate e.g. Larm. f....

Comment: I really don't know why the down votes.I am just asking is there simmilarity between the macroscopic precession and subatomic precession.So if we know that as a top spins faster its precession is slower and for a slower spin of a top the precession is faster can we just conclude that maybe subatomic particles act simmilarely.So if a particle spin is faster its precession(measured by Larmor frequency) is slower and for a slow particle spin its precession is faster so its Larmor frequency is higher.....

Comment: The important and clear difference between macroscopic and subatomic spin is that the subatomic spin doesn't change with time...

Comment: I think the two quoted sources answer the question. The relationship between magnetic moment and precession rate is perfectly clear in the quantum case. The concept of a rate of spin is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spinning top has angular momentum given by the product of the inertia tensor and the angular velocity. The angular momentum of a particle cannot be written in this way and so the question, which involves the angular velocity ('spin rate') of the particle, is, strictly, meaningless.

However this is an attempt to answer what I take to be the intent of the question. The answer is *NO* the precession rate for a spin in a magnetic field does not depend on the angular momentum $\mathbf{S}$, unlike a spinning top.

The analogy between the two *works* because in both cases there is a torque which we can write as $\mathbf{S}\times\mathbf{K}$, which produces a precession of $ \mathbf{S}$ about $\mathbf{K}$ with a rate given by $|\mathbf{K}|$. However the analogy cannot be pushed too far. For the spinning top the torque is $Ml\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{g}$, where $M$ is the mass, $l$ is the distance of the centre of mass from the support point and $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector along the spin axis. The angular momentum is $S \mathbf{n}$, so that $|\mathbf{K}|=Mgl/S$, inversely proportional to $S$. However for the magnetic dipole in a magnetic field the torque is $\mathbf{\mu}\times\mathbf{B}$, where the magnetic dipole is $\mathbf{\mu}=\gamma\mathbf{S}$, where $\gamma$ is the gyromagnetic ratio. This gives
$|\mathbf{K}|=\gamma B$, independent of $S$.